# Pagination is not working in WordPress custom template and custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, wordpress-theming

Pagination is not showing in my custom homepage template. Here is my code for the page:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Homepage Template
 * The main template file.
 * 
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area container">
        <div id="main" class="site-main  col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" role="main">
<?php $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; ?>
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'article',
            'paged'     => $paged
            );

        $articles = new WP_Query($args);
        if ( $articles->have_posts() ) :
            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( $articles->have_posts() ) : $articles->the_post();
       get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-article', get_post_format() );
        endwhile;
        the_posts_navigation();
        else :
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-article', 'none' );
        endif; ?>
        </div><!-- #main -->
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Does anybody know how to get pagination working?

Comment: Can u check after adding  'posts_per_page' => 5 in your $args ?

Comment: And also try with get_next_posts_link() and get_previous_posts_link(). Ref: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/pagination-with-wpquery-custom-post-type

Comment: yes i tried but still not working

Comment: hi **Chris** I'm using  that code you refer me this is working fine for me, but when I set a static page it's not working, Please help me how I can fix this now thanks